# accessing attributes in sequelize instanceMethods

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I'm adding an instance method to a sequelize model.  According to [the documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#expansion-of-models) I should be able to reference this.name, but the only value I can see is this.dataValues.name.  I have no reason to believe that the high quality documentation is wrong .... but why does this happen?

Also, there are no setters or getters available.  this.getDataValue / this.setDataValue work in getters / setters, but not in instanceMethods.

I can't find any relevant samples on the net - if you know of a project that reads (or better, writes) these values, please add that to your response.

```
module.exports = (sequelize: Sequelize, DataTypes: DataTypes) => {
  return sequelize.define<UserInstance, UserPojo>('User', {
      name: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
    }, {
      instanceMethods: {
        myMethod: (value) => {

          // this.name is undefined

          // this.dataValues.name IS defined ??

        }
      }, ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can probably see, I'm using Typescript.  I just examined the generated Javascript, and immediately saw the problem.

Typescript puts this at the top of the module:

```
var _this = this;
```

And references that '_this', rather than the one in the context of the function -- didn't realize that!  As soon as I changed this to traditional function() { } syntax, it worked.  So, if you're using typescript, you can do this:

```
myMethod: function(value: type) => void {

}
```

That is, you don't have to give up on typing your arguments and return value.